# How to test that `clear` command is working correctly in BASH?

Tags: bash, unit-testing

Now i try find the way to prove that a `clear` command is working correctly on my own `REPL`

Example

```
$ cd ~
$ pwd
/home/user
$ echo "hello"
hello
```

then type `clear`

```
$
```

but sometime some unexpected behavior is occurred after using a `clear` command

e.g.

```
[one blank line here]
$
```

A one blank line after using `clear` command is undesirable behavior and I hope this kind of bug can be detected automatically via a unit test. If you have any idea to prove that `clear` command is working correctly please purpose.

Comment: The job of `clear` is to send a sequence of characters. Interpreting this sequence is the job of the tty emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.  "clear" sends a sequence of bytes that tells the terminal to clear its screen.  Different terminals use different sequences.  There is a table called "termcap" (terminal capabilities) that lists the difference sequences for different types of terminals.  The environment variable "TERM" should be set to the type of terminal you are using.

TERM is usually set to "xterm", "xterm-color", "vt100", or related value.  On my Mac OS X Terminal it is set to "xterm-256color".

TERM should be set automatically for you.  If your OS is set up properly you shouldn't have to set it yourself.  However in the old days you had to set it manually.  Therefore you'll find a lot of old .profile/.bashrc/.cshrc files that set it.  Check to see if that is happening and remove that (comment it out) to see what is automatically set.

Your question boils down to "how can I tell if my TERM variable is set right?" and the answer is: You can't.  You could do things like clear the screen then ask the user if they saw their screen clear.  However, if programs did that on start-up, it would be very annoying.